# Thoughts over array creation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I made some thoughts over JavaScript and array creation and actual memory allocation and I would like to hear more opinions over that and whether am I correct.

So actual memory in a pc in random time could be like that:

[image: random representational of memory]

If I write: `var a = [];`

It will create an Array at the beginning of the memory.

If I write `a.push(1);`

It will delete the old Array and then create a new one that reserves more memory and there might not be enough continuous memory at that moment where is is stored so it will have to move the chunk in another place.

So if I know from the beginning what is the length of the Array it is better/faster to use `var a = new Array(5)` than `var a = []`.

Off course on the other hand objects since they don't reserve memory it does not have those problems so if I have:

```
var object = {};
```

and then

```
object.foo = bar;
```

This will just find the next available place of memory and update the pointer.
So if I don't know the exact length/items or care about the order its better to use an object because it does not makes this delete create new array process.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and what is the question? I am tempted to flag this as opinion based since you seem to ask for opinions and not have much of a question

Comment: a question could be when we add a property to an object is there situation whet it's relocated in memory?

Comment: You're mixing up unrelated terms. To use Java terminology, objects are like `HashMap<String, Object>`, whereas arrays are like `ArrayList<Object>`. They serve different purposes (e.g. objects in javascript do not directly offer features like iteration), and their memory management is implemented differently. It's also not defined anywhere that pushing an element onto an array destroys the old instance; it depends on the JSVM implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two remarks.

I. Arrays are slightly better preallocated, probably. When you create an array, it takes more memory than it has elements (an empty array has a few slots preallocated already, for instance), so when you add an element, it can be added to array immediately. When there is no more free space reserved, an array is reallocated: a larger contiguous chunk is requested from the free storage and all the elements stored in the array so far are copied there. So, as you see, reallocation is a relatively expensive operation, so your guess is quite right—when you know size of an array in advance (or at least a lower bound to it, large enough), you'd rather create an array of at least that exact size. To cope with that, arrays reserved sizes grow exponentially with reallocations, it allows to keep *average* time of adding an element relatively low (ammortized O(1), to be precise).

Note that you should differentiate between *preallocated* and *preoccupied* storage. When you create a non-empty array with `Array(5)`, it has five elements already, so its `size` is 5. When you create an empty array, it has no elements, i.e. its `size` is 0, but internally, it contains sufficient storage to make first few additions instant.

II. When reallocating, the old storage is not *deleted*, it simply becomes *unreachable* (as should all no more required JS objects do), so it is known to the VM to be unused by the program and can thus be marked free during the next GC run.